# Non Linear Equation unique solution

Tags: nonlinear-system, differential

Can anyone help me prove that for every unique y, there exists unique a and b in the following equation:

$$y = \frac{bm}{e^{(a+bm)} + 1}$$

Here m is constant.

Comment: I thought about use of  theorem for first order differential equation dicussed here: [link](https://ximera.osu.edu/ode/main/existUniqueNonlinear/existUniqueNonlinear)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @MalviPatel The claim is just not true... Just plot the contour levels of $f(u,v)=\frac{1}{e^{u+v}+1}$. The $(a,b)$ you search always exist, but are not unique.

Comment: if $m=0$ and $y\neq 0$, then $\not\exists\, a,b$.